# Тошнотворно(-)зеленый

Tags: раздельно-дефис

Подскажите, будьте добры, раздельно или через дефис?

Тошнотворно(-)зеленый

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Оба варианта возможны, причем обычно речь идет об **избыточности чего-либо**. К примеру, часто говорят: тошнотворно-сладкий запах.

Это может быть **оттенок цвета** с дефисным написанием: **тошнотворно-зеленый** (к примеру, подчеркнуто яркий).

Другой вариант:  **тошнотворно зеленый,** то есть насыщенный до тошнотворности.  Тогда это наречие перед прилагательным, раздельное написание.

Более нейтральным мне кажется  написание **через дефис**, но в сложных оттенках встречается и раздельное письмо.

Пример: Колонна плечистых телеграфных столбов косо стоит по пояс в этой скучной воде **тошнотворно сине-розового** цвета медуницы. [В. П. Катаев. Время, вперед! (1931-1932)]